# Modify CoreData entity attribute value via UITextView

Tags: ios, core-data, uitextfield, appdelegate

I have `UITextView` which shows some text data from CoreData entity.

I need the possibility to edit this text data and save changes after keyboard dismissed.

How to do that?

I know how to save data but I don't know how to dismiss keyboard if I tap outside `UITextView`. May be there is some native way to do that.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
...
}
```

Thanks for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To save data after you stop editing UITextView and have dismissed the keyboard,
   use TextView's Delegate method

   - (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView

In this method, save the new text in the Entity's appropriate property and save the managed object context to persist the data.

1. To dismiss to dismiss keyboard if you tap outside UITextView

   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
     {
     [`TextView` resignFirstResponder];
     }

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set the **delegate** for *UITextview* to current view.We have native code for when we click on return button on keyboard we will get the event using **UIKit.Framework**, Inside that function write your save or other logics.

**Code:**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    // -------  here is your logics  -------- //
}
```

textField => Your text field object.

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss the keyboard you can use.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
       [self.view endEditing:YES];
   }
```